# Do I use ngModel to bind a form to server scripts?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, data-binding, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Angular, working on my first project which is a hybrid mobile app. I am using Ionic/Angular.

In my app, each user account has their custom notification settings. There are about ten different types of notification settings that any given user could have toggled on or off. I have a checkbox form in my app on the "Settings" page.

How do I properly bind this data to the user account on the server? From my understanding, ngModel is useful when the input is used elsewhere in the app, while this use is only regarding notifications that happen based on server data changes.

Here is what I am currently thinking to do for this, though I hope to get some community input before implementing a specific solution. In my User Service that populates data to my User Module for app use, should I include a set of bool values that represent current notification settings? And could I then use data binding with ngModel to connect the checkbox form inputs to the User Module?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [ion-toggle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toggle/Toggle/) with a change output function. This way, you don't need a ngModel.

In your html:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label> Notification 1 </ion-label>
    <ion-toggle (ionChange)="toggleNotification('not1', $event.target.value)"> </ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label> Notification 2 </ion-label>
    <ion-toggle (ionChange)="toggleNotification('not2', $event.target.value)"> </ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

and in your typescript, you should receive this value and call your api server:

```
public toggleNotification(notification: string, value: boolean) {
  // Call your server based on the notification
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am using ion-toggle. As I said, this is my first go at an app, so I am learning the server-side connections as well.

Comment: Is there much difference in server time-cost to update the user's setting for each change? I was thinking I would track all of the changes and then call the server to update once when they leave the page. This to minimize costs of server calls